# C# datatable computing

Tags: c#, datatable

I am computing in the large datatable. The table name is templetable.

I am trying to calculate the sum from the 4th  column to the last column and save the results to another datatable. But I am getting errors as it says could not find the column "colPnow"

Any ideas?

```
DataView dv2 = new DataView(SP_dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < LoadIDcount; i++)
        {
            string IDnow = LoadID[i, 0];
            dv2.RowFilter = String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow);
            DataTable temptable = dv2.ToTable();

            for (int j = 0; j < 8760; j++)
            {
                string colPnow = SP_dt.Columns[j*2 + 4].ColumnName.ToString();
                double ColP_sum= (double)temptable.Compute("Sum(colPnow)", String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));
                string colQnow = SP_dt.Columns[j*2 + 5].ColumnName.ToString();
                double ColQ_sum = (double)temptable.Compute("Sum(colQnow)", String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));

                Load_dt.Rows[i][j * 2 + 2] = ColP_sum;
                Load_dt.Rows[i][j * 2 + 3] = ColQ_sum;
            }

        }
```

Comment: At what line does the error come up? Are you sure your datatable has a column with the name colPnow?

Comment: The column name does not have "colPnow". But colPnow is defined as  a string for column.

Comment: What if you try to change the compute line to: `double ColP_sum= (double)temptable.Compute(String.Format("Sum({0})", colPnow), String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not formatting your expression string correctly in the `Compute` method. Use another `String.Format` and it will work. Your `Compute` expression is currently literally equal to `"Sum(colPnow)"`. You want the actual column name string that is stored in your `colPnow` variable.

Change this part of your code to this:

```
string colPnow = SP_dt.Columns[j*2 + 4].ColumnName.ToString();
double ColP_sum= (double)temptable.Compute(String.Format("Sum([{0}])", colPnow),
                                           String.Format("Load_ID = '{0}'", IDnow));
```

The same should be done for your `colQnow` variable. I would also suggest you read how [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) works so that you can grasp the string formatting concept.

Comment: I have got the following error message when coming to second row of the code above:                                                                                               Additional information: Syntax error in aggregate argument: Expecting a single column argument with possible 'Child' qualifier.

Comment: Try enclosing your expression with square brackets `[` and `]`. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now the code is running. As it has a lot of loop calculation, it takes a long time and is still running. I am waiting to see the results. Thanks a lot! I have been thinking for days for how to calculate this in datatable. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: The running is complete. The code works perfect. Thanks a lot!